# Ubuntu removing user

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, user-accounts, administration

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 on Virtualbox in Windows 7. I gave admin permissions to a new account and deleted my old main Ubuntu user (the one with which I installed ubuntu). I also deleted the home directory for the old admin user. I had set autologin and password less login on the old account. So now whenever the system reboots, it seems to search for the old user home. e.g. I get errors like "Could not find /home//ICEAuthority", "Nautilus could not load desktop" or something like that. I can only work with Ctrl+Alt+f1 now. I think the problwm is because of the auto login. It stills searches for the old account for auto login. How can I disable auto-login or set auto login to the new account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo userdel -r [username]
```

Comment: I get this response: userdel: <old-user> home directory (/home/<old-user>) not found. But still same problem when i try to reboot..

Comment: Hey it worked after I shut down and turned it on again.. reboot did not work. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem. Glad to help :-)